# ViewModel code not running in NativeScript app

Tags: javascript, nativescript

In my login.xml file I have `<Page loaded = "loaded">`

In my login.js I have

```
exports.loaded = function(){ console.log("Hello"); };
```

and I have tried other functions on different views but nothing is running but up until today everything was working perfectly.

Comment: Binding works as expected - perhaps you should revise your imports and/or provide more details about your case. You can also try tns create myApp just to be sure that you don't have some local issues (as this will crate basix app with view-model)

Comment: I did as you said, set up a new app and ran it, it worked, went back to my first project ran it again and now it's up and running! Thanks of the help!